# Sumif Last date value in powerpivot

Tags: powerpivot, excel-2016, sumifs

I'm working with excel 2016 and have already loaded my data in PowerPivot

My data is as below (summarized):

Date    Time    Amount

9/20/2017   8:20    100

9/20/2017   9:20    200

9/20/2017   10:20   **180**

9/21/2017   9:00    50

9/22/2017   22:00   **110**

All I want is to create a measure so that for each date, I sum the last Amount value (indicated in bold); so in the example, the desired value would be 290.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the latest Time by day, and then use this in a measure.

Find the maximum time of date:

```
mymaxtime=CALCULATE(MAX(myfact[Time]);filter(myfact;myfact[Date]=EARLIER(myfact[Date])))
```

You can then use this calculated column in a new measure:

```
mycalculation:=CALCULATE(sum(myfact[Amount]);filter(myfact;myfact[Time]=(myfact[mymaxtime])))
```

Screenshot of the result:
[image: Powerpivot sheet]